# No matching version found for react-dev-utils@^12.0.0

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I am trying to create a react app using `npx create-react-app client`.

I get the following error:

```
Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for react-dev-utils@^12.0.0.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\uzair\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-02-04T05_42_25_207Z-debug-0.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --no-audit --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting client/ from C:\Projects\Exhibition Gate\ExhibitionGate
Done.
```

[Find Error Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKM4p.png)

Answer (score 0):

When you run `npx create-react-app client`, it will download all needed development dependencies.
These are usually specified in the `package.json`

It's claiming that it can't find `react-dev-utils@^12.0.0`

## 1.figure out if this package exists

[react-dev-utils@12.0.0](https://unpkg.com/browse/react-dev-utils@12.0.0/) exists, so this should be fine.

## 2. Check if you can download it

Make sure you can actually download it. You company might be blocking it in proxies and whatnot.

```
# create a new directory to test this in
mkdir test_app

# create a new empty package.json file
npm init -y

# add react-dev-utils@^12.0.0 to check it can be found.
npm install react-dev-utils@^12.0.0
```

when everything goes to plan. This should run for a couple of seconds and download the files required.
you would end up with a `node_modules` folder with all the files needed by `react-dev-utils@12.0.0`

If it doesn't then you should try to resolve whatever issue it prompts.

One thing to check is what registry has been set:

```
npm config get registry
> https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

## 3. Caches that missbehave

You might want to clear caches to rule out any incorrect/stale caches.

```
npm cache clean --force
```